# Clicking "space" submitted my question before I was ready to submit it

Tags: support

I posted a question on Stack Overflow. When I typed the tags I clicked "Tab" (I think I had to click "space"). I clicked "space" and my question was submitted before I had the chance to review it! Why does clicking "space" submit the question and can you fix this bug? I think clicking "space" should not submit any form on any website. I'm using Google Chrome but it may happen on other browsers.

Comment: It's a basic browser behavior. Stack Exchange can't and should not "fix" this, just be more careful and keep in mind that SPACE and ENTER have same result when the focus is on a button.

Comment: Thanks for your comments, but I clicked "space" to confirm the tags and I didn't intend to submit the form. I didn't intend to move the focus to the submit button and I didn't intend to submit.

Answer (score 4):

Tabbing out of the tags field will put the focus on the "Post Your Question" button - pressing space (or enter) will at that point cause the form to submit.

That's how browsers behave - we are not going to change the default browser behavior as that would break expected behavior.

Comment: What is the expected behavior here? Tabbing out of the question box doesn't work anyways, so why it should work for the tag box?

Comment: @Jan - huh? Tabbing out of the question box takes to the tags box.

Comment: Oops, that's a part of a userscript. Maybe this feature request should be forwarded to the author of that userscript?